# Can WiDi stream from TV to PC?

Tags: streaming, htpc

I know WiDi is for streaming from PC to TV, but I have a scenario where I want the TV-signal streamed to a HTPC in another room, as a secondary screen duplicating the TV-image. I s this possible with WiDi or is it only possible the other way around?

The problem I'm trying to solve is this:

I have a TV in my living room (which supports widi) and (soon) a htpc/all-in-one-pc in the kitchen. The htpc has HDMI-out and in as well as the TV. I could connect them using HDMI-cables but I rather use wireless transfer of course. I haven't bought the htpc yet but I'm wondering if it's any idea of getting one with WiDi-support if I really only need it for streaming from the TV to the HTPC to replicate the image so I can continue watch whatever is on the TV while I'm in the kitchen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. WiDi will allow streaming from a PC to a screen/projector, but you would need the tuner component to act as a PC, and your PC to pretend to be a projector to do that over WiDi